# Eleventy Static Image Generation

Tags: eleventy, wp-graphql

I'm using Eleventy, Eleventy-Fetch and WPGraphQL to generate a static version of a WordPress site.  All works as required, however I was wondering if it's possible to use a similar setup to generate images.  I could use WPGraphQL to get a list of images (MediaItems), I should be able to pass the image URL to Eleventy-Image and generate multiple optimised versions of image.  However I'm unsure how to actually implement this with Eleventy?